# Motivation behind using complex numbers in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, motivation

There's a common technique in couting/tiling problems in  Olympiad which is to use complex numbers. I'm giving some examples:

1. (IMO 1995 P6) Let $p > 2$ be a prime number and let $A = \{1, \cdots, 2p \}$. Find the number of subsets of $A$ each havinig $p$ elements and whose sum is divisible by $p$.

> The solution to the above problem is to let $\zeta = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}}$ and let $x_j$ be the number of subsets of $A$ such that $|X| = p$ and $m(X) \equiv j \mod p$ ($m(X)$ denotes $\sum_{i \in X} x$). Now the rest of the solution is based on using $\sum_{0 \leq j \leq p-1} x_j \zeta^j = [X^p](X+\epsilon)(X+\epsilon^2) \cdots (X+ \zeta^{2p}) = [X^p](x^p+1)^2$ and the lemma that if $a_0 + a_1 \zeta + \cdots + a_{p-1} \zeta^{p-1} = 0$, then $a_0 = a_1 = \cdots = a_{p-1}$.

There's another problem which uses complex numbers, but in a different way

2. (Baltic Contest 1998) Can we tile $13 \times 13$ table from which we can remove the central unit square using only $4 \times 1$ and $1 \times 4$ rectangles ?

> The answer is no, and the solution is based on putting the number $i^{k+2j}$ on the cell $(k, j)$, and then summing that in two ways to derive a contradiction.

---

My question is while these applications are cute, they're looking just like a random trick which happens to be useful rather than part of a more general thing.

Is there a way to motivate such applications of complex numbers ? (For example, invariants are also a common trick in olympiad combinatorics problems which involves some process. But some invariants, [which seemingly falls from the sky](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h90046p3461926), can often be well motivated using [group theory](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h90046p527567) )

Is this "trick" part of a more general technique which is very useful ?

Comment: More generally, real and complex analysis often helps in combinatorics. For instance, power series are often used by identifying the coefficients of two different development of the same function.

Comment: These are not really applications of *complex* numbers but just roots of unity. That they could be viewed in $\mathbf C$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Relevant words: root-of-unity filter; discrete Fourier transform; cyclic sieving. I think "discrete Fourier inversion" is the oldest and probably the best-known metaphor; roughly speaking, you're taking the convolution of a discrete "wave" with a "pure sine wave" (again, the discrete version of it -- i.e., just $\zeta^{kn}$ for fixed $k$ and variable $n$, with $\zeta$ being a fixed root of unity), and this convolution "filters out" all but the right frequency in your discrete "wave".

Comment: Note that the 2nd problem, about tiling rectangles, can be generalized: If a rectangle is partitioned into finitely many little rectangles such that each little rectangle has at least one integer side, then the big rectangle must also have at least one integer side. (To see how this yields your problem, just shrink your rectangle by the factor of $4$.) See http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/rectangles/ for a discussion of this general problem and further variants. (Note that the "proof by complex integration" is just classical Fourier analysis.)

Comment: what is $\epsilon$ in the solution for question 1?

Comment: @Ali Sorry, it's $\zeta$. You can replace all occurances of $\epsilon$ by $\zeta$ in that; I'll fix it later once I get near my laptop