# The soccer splitting problem in arbitrary ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

There's a folklore problem:

> Let $x_1, \cdots, x_{23} \in \mathbb{Z}$ be the weights of $23$ soccer players. Now Master Yoda want's to form two soccer teams with $11$ players each. Turns out for any $1 \leq i \leq 23$, one can partition $\{1, \cdots, 23 \} - \{ i \}$ into two disjont sets $A, B$ with $|A| = |B| = 11$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{k \in A} x_k = \sum_{k \in B} x_k$. Prove that all numbers must be equal.

The solution is well known and is not very hard for $\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm wondering replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ by which commutative ring with unit $R$ makes the problem false.

If $R = \mathbb{Q}$, then it's also same as $\mathbb{Z}$ (and the answer is affirmative), just multiply everything by the LCM of the numerators to reduce it to the case $R = \mathbb{Z}$.

If $R = \mathbb{R}$, then also the problem is true, but you need a lemma by Dirichlet (which is proven by PHP) to reduce it to the case $R = \mathbb{Z}$.

If $R = \mathbb{C}$, then also the problem is true. Because if $\displaystyle \sum_{k \in A} z_k = \sum_{k \in B} z_k \Rightarrow \sum_{k \in A} \text{Re}(z_k) = \sum_{k \in B} \text{Re}(z_k)$, and by the previous one $R = \mathbb{R}$ applied to the real components, you get $\text{Re}(z_i) = \text{Re}(z_j)$ for all $i, j$. Similarly you prove the imaginary componenets are same, so all numbers are same.

If $R = \mathbb{Q}[x], \mathbb{C}[x], \mathbb{R}[x], M_{m,n}(\mathbb{Q}),  M_{m,n}(\mathbb{Z}),  M_{m,n}(\mathbb{C}),  M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R}) $, even then the problem is true since you can look at the problem "component wise" and reduce it to the above cases.

However I have no idea whether the problem is true when $R = \mathbb{Z}_p$ for some prime $p$ or in some other rings. Is it true for all rings, or are there some rings for which this problem doesn't hold ? If it's false for some rings, are there any characterizations for such rings ?

Comment: It still holds for $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by a parity argument.

Comment: And it doesn't hold for $\mathbb{Z}_3$ I think. Choice is 12x 1 and 11 x -1

Comment: So assuming that the characteristic is zero seems reasonable. Is there anything special about the number 23 or could one also use any other odd number here.

Comment: @HenrikRueping Ya one can use any other odd number here.

Comment: @alxchen What is an elegant solution of the problem for $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: My approach was to reduce it to $\mathbb{R},$ and then transform the problem into a homogeneous equation, and count the dimension of the null space. Of course, this gives the result for $\mathbb{Z}$ already, but is there a more elementary way of seeing the result?

Comment: @Dedalus Um I don't see how you solve it by "reducing" the case $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Can you explain ?

Comment: @Dedalus For the solution for $\mathbb{Z}$, firstly assume the gcd of all elements is $1$ (otherwise divide by the common gcd). Then substract one from everything. Repeat until atleast one of the number becomes zero. Now note that all other numbers MUST be zero at this step, which concludes the result.

Comment: @Dedalus For reducing  $R = \mathbb{R}$ to $R = \mathbb{Z}$, you need the following lemma: Given any finite set $S$ of real numbers, and an $\epsilon > 0$, one can define a function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and a positive integer $n$ such that for all $x \in S$ we have $|f(x) - nx| < \epsilon$

Comment: @alxchen Sorry, why must all numbers be zero at that step?

Comment: The original problem follows from the fact that the $23 \times 23$-matrix $\left(1-\delta_{i,j}\right)_{1\leq i\leq 23,\ 1\leq j\leq 23}$ is invertible over $\mathbb{F}_2$, whence every matrix whose entries are $\pm \left(1-\delta_{i,j}\right)$ must have a trivial kernel over $\mathbb{Z}$ (since its determinant is odd). This shows automatically that the problem also holds over fields of sufficiently large positive characteristic (because the nonzero determinants of all such matrices must be bounded from above).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Ahh nice. I suppose that answers the question posed below my answer.

Comment: I have same question as @Dedalus and I'm wondering if you need the weights to actually by positive for that argument to work?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Sorry for being dense, but isn’t the matrix of the form $(a_{ij}(1-\delta_{ij}))$ for $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}?$ How do I reduce this to your situation?

Comment: @dedalus Hmm I think the argument should be that the $x_i$ end up multiplied by the matrix but I don't particularly see how you end up getting equality rather than 0, which isn't actually enough I think. Not sure.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Are you sure the matrix is invertible over $\mathbb{F}_2?$ I put the matrix in Sage and seem to get that the determinant of your matrix is actually $22,$ which surely is zero mod $2.$ Just to be clear, we are talking about the matrix whose first row is $[0,1,1,1,1...],$ whose second row is $[1,0,1,1...],$ third row is $[1,1,0,1,1,...]$ and so on, right?

Comment: @Dedalus: Oops, sorry; I was wrong (and yes, you correctly understood my matrix). The argument needs to be subtler: We need to show that the kernel of the matrix is spanned by $\left(1,1,\ldots,1\right)^T$. To do that, merely check that $\left(1,1,\ldots,1\right)^T$ belongs to the kernel, and that the rank of the matrix is at least $22$ (since its northwestern $22 \times 22$-minor is $1 \mod 2$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Then I agree with your argument! Beautiful.  It was something similar I had in mind for $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @darijgrinberg or Dedalus one of you want to write up the argument as an answer please? It adds a lot of extra information for Fields, and comments might get purged.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm very sorry for a off topic comment but since you were an IMO Gold Medallist and now working in combinatorics, can you answer this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877155/motivation-behind-using-complex-numbers-in-combinatorics ? Thanks.

Comment: @DRF: I'll put this on my long list of things to write up, though I can't guarantee any of them actually getting done (the curse of combinatorics is that you often come up with proofs faster than you can write them down).

Comment: [This was originally crossposted simultaneously.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/307987/19965) Please don't do that. At least, not without acknowledging you are doing that.

Answer (score 3):

So I think $\mathbb{Z}_3$ provides a counterexample. If you choose the weights of the players as 12 x 1 and 11 x -1 it breaks.

Proof.: You can only make two choices as to what gets taken away.

Case 1) the player left out has weight 1. Then you get $11 \times 1$ and $11 \times -1$. Choosing a split of $10$ players with weight $1$ and one with weight $-1$ and $10$ players with weight $-1$ and one with weight $1$, gives $(9\times 1)+ 1+(-1)=0+0$ and $(9 \times -1)+(-1)+1=0+0$.

Case 2) the player left out has weight -1. Then you get $12 \times 1$ and $10 \times -1$. But than you can split them evenly into $6\times 1$ and $5\times -1$ on each side.

Edit: so turns out you can come up with a much easier counterexample which works for all $\mathbb{Z}_k$ where $k\leq 11$ and odd.

Choose the weights to be $23-k$ times $0$ and $k$ times $a\neq 0$. Then if you leave out a $0$ weight players then all the $a$ weight players on the same team have weight $ka=0$ and if you leave out an $a$ weight player you put $(k-1)/2$ $a$-weight players on each team.

Edit 2: Ok so if you specify only ring with unit then you're out of luck with a bound. There exist arbitrarily large rings where counterexamples exist. Namely all rings of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{pk}$ where $p\leq 11$ is odd and $k>1$ is arbitrary. The counterexample then is $23-p$ zeroes and $p$ many $k$'s. The argument is the same as in edit 1. Choose a $0$ and you make a team of $p$ $k$'s padded with zeroes, choose $k$ and you have even number of $k$'s to split between the two teams.

Obviously this type of (large) example goes away if you require not a ring but an integral domain.

Comment: Well yeah I guess this works, but is it false for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ when $p$ is arbitrarily large ?

Comment: @alxchen Yeah that's a good question. It's easy to get $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p<11$. I'll add that in a bit

Comment: @alxchen Added some more information about counterexamples

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't write this in the comment but $Z_{13}$ provides another counterexample: Eight 1s, one 5, and fourteen 0s. Similarly for $Z_{17}$ take ten 1's, one 7, and twelve 0s.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  If you work at it, you can find Questions to answer or post good Questions of your own that will earn enough reputation (50 pts.) to allow commenting on the posts of others (you can already comment on your own posts and on Answers to your Questions).

Comment: I am quite ready to believe it's true but it would be great if you pointed out the argument. You have three choices to remove in these cases. The 0 is easy, the 1's and seven/five doesn't seem to be quite a 1 second trivial case.

Comment: Hmm ok they are 2 second trivial cases got them once i posted the comment, still worth explaining them I think. It sort of seems as though this might transfer further? I'm not sure.

Comment: It doesn't transfer for 23 but generally for $2N+1$ (here in our case $N=11$), the same setup (i.e. a bunch of 1s, one other number, and then a bunch of 0s) works to show that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a counterexample for all $p<2N$.

Comment: For 23 players, the highest prime I can go is 37: take four 4s, six 3s and thirteen 0s. Take a zero out, divide the rest evenly. Take a four out, put 3, 4, 4, 4 and seven 0s in one set and the rest of the numbers in another set. Take a three out, then put all the rest of nonzero numbers in one group with two more 0s, and the other eleven 0s in one group.

Comment: The more general problem can be asked as follows. Let $N$ and $k,l<N$ be positive integers. An Abelian group $G$ is said to have the $(N,k,l)$ division property if there exists a list $x_1,\ldots, x_N$ in $G$, not all of its terms zero simultaneously, such that after removing any $k$ members of the list the remaining terms can be divided into $l$ groups of equal size and equal sum. One can prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p$ large enough do not have the $(N,k,l)$ division property. The harder question is to find the largest $p=C(N,k,l)$ for which the property holds.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the source of the problem? I think it is a nice elementary problem that one could use for an undergraduate research project.